# Get all setters from a complex object

Tags: c#

I have an object that holds several value types and other objects.
I want to use reflection that would do something for every setter found.

For instance object A has 3 fieds and a children object B that has another 3 fields.
So when i have object A i would need to do something for all 6 setters.

Hope i make sense!

Comment: I know it's not what you asked for, but you should consider if Castle Dynamic Proxy is useful for what you're trying to achieve: http://www.castleproject.org/dynamicproxy/index.html

Comment: You make sense, but you haven't said what problem you're having. Do you need someone to write this for you, or have you started to write it but encountered a problem?

Comment: actualy i dont know how to go dynamicly tru entire object tree to get all setters (no matter how many levels there are).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is recursive, so you'll have a recursive algorithm:

for your Object A, get its type, get its setters and get its fields. 
For each field, recursively get the type, the setters, the fields, and so on.

Along the way, call a delegate for each setter found. Or put them in a list and call the delegate at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Use `object.GetType().GetProperties()` to get an array of all the properties. For each property, you can get the type of the property. You can then, recursively, use `GetProperties()` on that type, to get the properties.